# modify nodejs require() to search for .min.js

Tags: node.js

**O/S is ubuntu 16, node version is 4.2.6.**

I have source / development code and run / distribution code, the source.js files are minified and mangled to create equivalent source.min.js files, and I would like for node js require to automatically search for .min.js files as well as .js files.

But as I have a lot of files, I would prefer not to have to go through every require in every file and instead modify the built-in require() function.

This is a very simple implementation of a stand alone function, but how can I modify the built-in function to behave the same way ?

```
function require(file){
    try{return require(file)} 
    catch(e){return require(file+='.min.js')}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by modifying prototype function `require` of `Module class` and apply it globally

Here is how you can do it :

```
var pathModule = require('path');
var assert = require('assert').ok;

module.constructor.prototype.require = function (path) {
    var self = this;
    assert(typeof path === 'string', 'path must be a string');
    assert(path, 'missing path');

    try {
        return self.constructor._load(path, self);
    } catch (err) {
        // if module not found, we have nothing to do, simply throw it back.
        if (err.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND') {
            throw err;
        }
        // resolve the path to get absolute path
        path = pathModule.resolve(__dirname, path+".min.js")

        // Write to log or whatever
        console.log('Error in file: ' + path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, that does appear to work but it appears that I would need to call it up in every module. I have added the code into the main app.js file, and while it works there, other modules are still not able to resolve the files. is there any way to make this global ?

Comment: As per my understanding Yes, unfortunately you will need to call it in every file. You might get some insight [from here](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/)